# Can I upload an ImageField directly from the Django admin to S3 using django-storages and boto?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I'm attempting to upload the image component of an ImageField directly to S3 through the django admin when I create a record.  Is it possible to achieve this directly by simply specifying the AWS S3 url for static files in

```
MEDIA_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp/media/'
```

and specifying boto in:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

or is it necessary to run the collectstatic command/upload using a homegrown form to submit to AWS.  django-storages docs give no real indication of whether this is possible and preliminary attempts to upload images to S3 using admin have not yielded results.

Comment: Since Django 1.3 STATICS and MEDIA are separate. see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#extended-static-files-handling

Answer (score 3):

I think staticfiles != media files. But I also think you can define storage for media file too, so auto upload to S3 should be a possibility.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/ 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE

Comment: thanks, it was the **DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE** which was the problem, I hadn't set it correctly.  As a follow up (as I hadn't read this anywhere) it _is_ possible to upload files directly from django admin to S3 without using collectstatic etc